# Word automation - Selection.InsertFile ignores page orientation

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, word-automation

I an writing a vb.net program with which I want to combine different word files to a single one - based on a template.

I am using this line of code in a for-each-documents-loop:

```
oWord.Selection.InsertFile(DocumentFilename, "", False, False, False)
```

I also tried these lines:

```
oWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:=DocumentFilename, Range:="", _        ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False)
```

or

```
 oWord.Selection.InsertFile(FileName:=DocumentFilename, ConfirmConversions:=False)
```

Generally that works.
But my problem is:
If a document has breaks in it where e.g. page 1-5 is portrait, page 6 in landscape and page 7- is portrait again, my code ignores that fact and adds all pages in portrait

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting that late. Yes I found a solution. I am adding a section break at the beginning of each document:

```
oDocQuell = oWordQuell.Documents.Add(txtSourcedrive.Text & "\" & LI.ToString)
oWordQuell.Selection.HomeKey(Unit:=Word.WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesHeaderStory)  ' Word-VBA: Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
oWordQuell.Selection.InsertBreak(Type:=Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous) ' Word-VBA: Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
```